# How to implement a better fallback when a selected option in a dropdown list (a mapped select Input in React) is no longer exist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select

I have a dropdown list called Reward. All the options in the dropdown list are populated from the info submitted by users elsewhere, meaning the content of the dropdown list is dynamic.

This is how it looks:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.state = {
       ...
       reward: this.props.bucket.reward || "",
       ...
    };

    ...
    this.onBucketRewardChanged = this.onBucketRewardChanged.bind(this);
    ...
}

render() {
…
<div className="col-md-2">
   <label>
      <span className={''}>Reward<br/></span>
   </label>
   <select className="form-control"
         value={this.state.reward}
         onChange={(e) => this.onBucketRewardChanged(bucketIdx, e)}>
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select a reward ...</option>
      {rewards.map(this.renderRewardIDs)}
   </select>
</div>
}

renderRewardIDs(reward, idx) {
   return (
      <option key={idx} value={reward.id}>{reward.id}</option>
   );
}

onBucketRewardChanged(bucketIdx, event) {
   this.setState({reward: event.target.value});
   …
}
```

The Reward dropdown list is an array of rewards that are built dynamically using a user input somewhere else, so the options in the reward list can be changed (added or deleted) from time to time. The above code works, except when the previously selected value is no longer exists. When a reward option is deleted, in the entry where that reward option was previously selected, I want to fall back to the default value, which is “” and displaying “Please select a reward ...”. However, in my current implementation (above), the very 1st value in the dropdown list is displayed (as if it is selected), but when the form is saved, nothing is saved, since it is not actually being selected.

I’d like the default value, “Please select a reward”, being displayed in the reward field when the previously chosen option was deleted, that will hopefully remind users to explicitly reselect one, but I cannot figure out how to make that happen. I'm still new to React, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In order to do this, you want to `value` property of `option` to be passed down from either your component's `state` or its `props`.

Comment: @LindaPaiste could you please elaborate on that, as what you mean by "pass down"? the reward is initialized as this.props.bucket.reward, then it is always set as this.state.reward.

Comment: Ignore that comment, I was confused between the `option` and the `select`.  I was seeing the `value=""` on the `option` and thinking that you were not using a controlled select, but you are.

Comment: This is maybe a bit hard for me to debug because there is more going on outside of just the component that you've posted.  You initialize `this.state.reward` to `this.props.bucket.reward` but you aren't listening for changes in it.  Probably that should not be in the component state at all.  Use `this.props.bucket.reward` directly as the `value` for the select and have a prop which is a callback that updates the source of `this.props.bucket.reward` when the `select` value changes.  Read the section on [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).